# Discover OpenID Connect Provider Issuer

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, openid, openid-connect, webfinger

In the OpenID Connect Discovery 1.0 spec, section [User Input using E-Mail Address Syntax](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html#EmailSyntax)  they have this example:

```
  GET /.well-known/webfinger
    ?resource=acct%3Ajoe%40example.com
    &rel=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fspecs%2Fconnect%2F1.0%2Fissuer
    HTTP/1.1
  Host: example.com

  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Content-Type: application/jrd+json

  {
   "subject": "acct:joe@example.com",
   "links":
    [
     {
      "rel": "http://openid.net/specs/connect/1.0/issuer",
      "href": "https://server.example.com"
     }
    ]
  }
```

I tried

```
curl -GLv http://yahoo.com/.well-known/webfinger \
    --data-urlencode "resource=acct:myrealname@yahoo.com" \
    --data-urlencode "rel=http://openid.net/specs/connect/1.0/issuer"
```

I also tried

```
curl -GLv http://gmail.com/.well-known/webfinger \
    --data-urlencode "resource=acct:myrealname@gmail.com" \
    --data-urlencode "rel=http://openid.net/specs/connect/1.0/issuer"
```

among a few. But all I get is `404 Not Found`.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong, or there might be no place on the Internet that will actually return the `200 OK` shown in the example above.

My question is, given an OpenID (I mean what the user types here

[image]

), how do you determine where the OpenID Provider Issuer is?  In other words, if I want to allow logins via [OpenId Connect](http://openid.net/connect/), do I ***have*** to keep my own map from OpenID patterns to OpenID issuers?

Answer (score 2):

OpenID Connect is different from OpenID 2.0. Yahoo supports OpenID 2.0 but does not support OpenID Connect + Discovery yet, hence the 404. Here's a place on the internet that returns 200 OK:

```
curl -GLv https://seed.gluu.org/.well-known/webfinger \
    --data-urlencode "resource=acct:mike@seed.gluu.org" \
    --data-urlencode "rel=http://openid.net/specs/connect/1.0/issuer"
```

Comment: It works!  Now, since this seems to be the only place that implements OpenId Connect Discovery, how am I supposed to handle discovery? My own lookup table?

Comment: one can implement a functional OpenID Connect Discovery without the webfinger part: just ask the user for a domain name instead of an accountname/username and pull OpenID Connect metadata directly from https://<domainname>/.well-known/openid-configuration; there are quite a number of OpenID Connect implementations that conform to this; this is less flexible wrt. binding between users and domains and the user should know the domain for the OP which makes it harder; e.g. for selecting Google one would have to enter "accounts.google.com"; you could offer the big consumer OPs in a dropdown menu

Answer (score 1):

The WebFinger spec is relatively new and OpenID Connect is even newer, so neither is widely deployed, yet.  You can get info from my personal account:

$ curl https://packetizer.com/.well-known/webfinger?resource=acct%3Apaulej%40packetizer.com

I do not have OpenID Connect implemented (yet), but ping me if you want to test with general WebFinger queries.  I can have my server emit anything you want to test.